# Learning Rails 4, one long html page, adding a contact us form

Tags: html, ruby-on-rails

I am working on my simple one page personal website, I like ruby on rails and I am using rails 4.
I have one page only called home.html.erb, Kind of like a scrolling page. Now at the bottom of that page I want to add a contact me form, where someone can put in his name, cell, other data, a message, and hit send. 
Most tutorials I found on this topic basically generate a new page and a new controller, I don;t want that.

How can I achieve this in the same page I am working in?

Comment: You essentially just do what the tutorial would do, but instead of using the new controller, append the stuff to the end of your home one.  The one thing outside of that controller is with submitting it, you might want to submit it to a different controller (to handle the data and then redirect you back home)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could add a form to the bottom using rails [form helpers](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/form_helpers.html) and send the information to the server via [ajax](http://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/working_with_javascript_in_rails.html)

Answer (score 0):

check [this railscast out](http://railscasts.com/episodes/326-activeattr?view=asciicast). Though it's not Rails 4, it should still work.

Answer (score 0):

It's easy to add the form to the bottom of your page, simply by placing the HTML you might otherwise have on it's own page to the bottom of your main page. Similarly, you can put the instructions for what to do with the data in your main controller without any issues.

What would be tougher to avoid would be the need to generate a new model so you have a table to store this information – unless you write it to a txt file, or send it to yourself via email.

Here is code for creating a form NOT connected to a model:

```
<% form_tag(:action => 'contact_me') %<
<table>
<tr>
  <td><%= label_tag(:name) %></td>
  <td><%= text_field_tag(:name) %></td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td><%= label_tag(:cell) %></td>
  <td><%= text_field_tag(:cell) %></td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td>&nbsp;</td>
  <td><%= submit_tag("Send Info") %></td>
</tr>
</table>
```

If you plan to create a model:

```
<% form_for(:contact_me, :url => {:action => 'create', :controller => 'main'}) do |f| %>
<table>
<tr>
  <td><%= f.label(:name) %></td>
  <td><%= f.text_field(:name) %></td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td><%= f.label(:cell) %></td>
  <td><%= f.text_field(:cell) %></td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td>&nbsp;</td>
  <td><%= submit_tag("Send Info") %></td>
</tr>
</table>
```

The latter is simpler, because your controller can simply be:

```
def create
  @contact = Contact.new(contact_params)
  @contact.save
  redirect_to(:action => 'main')
end

private

def contact_params
  params.require(:contact_me).permit(:name, :cell)
end
```